# How to call a function inside eloquent Model directly without query?

Tags: php, laravel

I have function showItemList inside User class

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    //...

    protected $item = ['axe', 'sword', 'knife'];

    public function showItemList() {
        return $this->$item;
    }
}
```

In my controller it's possible to use this.

```
$id = 1;
$user = User::find($id);
$user -> showItemList();
```

But how can I just call this function directly(irrelevant to $id query)?

I looks for something like below (sure now it's not working):

```
$list = User::showItemList();
```

Comment: `protected static $item = ['axe', 'sword', 'knife'];

    public static function showItemList() {
        return self::$item;
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the static protected variable and return it from static method.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    //...
    static protected $item = ['axe', 'sword', 'knife'];

    public static function showItemList() {
        return self::$item;
    }
}
```